# How can add an additional row to a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, union

I have a LINQ query that retrieves rows from a dataset and binds it to a Winforms combobox:

```
namespace KimHongAutoAccessory.Forms
{
    public partial class EngineFilter : Form
    {
        public EngineFilter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void EngineFilter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.engineFilterTableAdapter.Fill(this.manufacturerEngine.EngineFilter);

            var manufacturers = (from m in manufacturerEngine.EngineFilter
                                 select new { m.ManufacturerID, m.Manufacturer })
                                 .Distinct().ToList();

            cboManufacturerFilter.DataSource = manufacturers.ToArray();
            cboManufacturerFilter.DisplayMember = "Manufacturer";
            cboManufacturerFilter.ValueMember = "ManufacturerID";


        }
    }
}
```

But I want to add a union item to the combobox like the word "[All]":

```
|-------|
|TOYOTA |
|-------|
|KUBOTA |
|-------|
|FORD   |
|-------|
|[All]  |
|-------|
```

Can anybody give me a trick?

Comment: When we see 'combobox' we would like to know if it's WinForms, WebForms, WPF, ...  You should see an _edit_ buton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably your "(All)" item would have a special value for its ID so you know when it has been selected. Let's assume its ID is -1.

```
var manufacturers = (from m in manufacturerEngine.EngineFilter
                     select new { m.ManufacturerID, m.Manufacturer }
                    ).Distinct().ToList();

manufactorers.Add(new { ManufacturerID = -1, Manufacturer = "(All)" });

cboManufacturerFilter.DataSource = manufacturers.ToArray();
// ... etc ...
```

Comment: I still have 2 complains: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments
Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'

Comment: @sovantha Hmm. That should work unless you have a typo in one of your properties. Provided the properties of the anonymous type match the type in the list, it should compile fine. Unless ... is m.Manufacturer a string or some compex type?

Comment: @sovantha How about ManufacturerID? Did I guess right in that it's an int? Or is it a Guid or something?

Comment: I would bet that `ManufacturerID` isn't an integer, but a GUID, string, or some other type. The second anonymous variable is using an integer, so for this error to occur the first anonymous type is using something else.

Comment: My dataset is a join query. Is it because of that?

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with the original query, because you're projecting out to an anonymous type. You just need to match the properties in the Add statement so it compiles.

Comment: I have no idea to do this. Pl give me an example.

Comment: @sovantha Start by answering my question above. What type is "ManufacturerID"?

Comment: Well, I go and change the ManufacturerID column datatype to string in my dataset, then it works. Thanks Matt hamilton.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example for using Union in LINQ using number for clarity.

```
        var A = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        var L = (from a in A where a > 5 select a)
            .Distinct()
            .Union(new int[]{-1})
            .ToList();
```

OR in your domain:

```
        var manufacturers = new []{ManufacturerID=-1, Manufacturer="(ALL)"}).AsEnumerable()
                      .Union(from m in manufacturerEngine.EngineFilter 
                             select new { m.ManufacturerID, m.Manufacturer })
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE (closer to the problem domain)**

```
    public class Manufacturer
    {
        public Manufacturer(int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void test222()
    {
        var L = new List<Manufacturer>() { new Manufacturer(1, "Abc"), new Manufacturer(2, "def"), new Manufacturer(3, "hij"), new Manufacturer(4, "klm"), new Manufacturer(5, "nop"), new Manufacturer(6, "qrs"), new Manufacturer(7, "tuv"), new Manufacturer(8, "wxyz") };

        var manufacturers = 
            new Manufacturer[] { new Manufacturer(-1, "[ALL]") }.AsEnumerable()
            .Union(from m in L select new Manufacturer(m.id, m.name)).Distinct().ToList();            
    }
```

N.B. if you want to initialise without a constructor, do this:

```
    new Manufacturer() {id=-1,name="[All]"}
```

this means the same thing.

Comment: You need the `new [] {...}` inside of the `.Union()`.  If you want this to be the first item instead of the last you can put the query in the `.Union()`.  You may also need `.AsEnumerable()` to force the query to execute.

Comment: Still the same errors. Error 1 The name 'ManufacturerID' does not exist in the current context. Error 2 The name 'Manufacturer' does not exist in the current context
Error 3 No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Comment: okay.  I can't see what type is in your list... so, try this: new YOUR_CLASS_NAME []{...

Comment: @sovantha: if you are still having issues, please post some simple class definitions + initialization routine so that I can duplicate.

Comment: I'll be back in a while to look at this.  I'll make some assumptions about your data... or you could create some simple classes with manufacturer id & name.  Are these the only properties that you need?

Comment: @sovantha: I just provided another example for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but thought I'd leave this here for the next guy =)
I was able add an anonymous object to an anonymous list below (.net 4.5)

```
var manufacturers = (from m in manufacturerEngine.EngineFilter
                     select new 
                     { 
                         ManufacturerID = (int)m.ManufacturerID, 
                         Manufacturer = m.Manufacturer 
                     }).ToList();

var allItem = new {
    ManufacturerID = (int)-1,
    Manufacturer = "ALL"
};

manufacturers.add(allItem);
```

Hope this helps.